# continuity of a Utility function in Vn-M framework

Tags: microeconomics

I consider a prize space $[1;10]$, with the space of all probability measures with finite support $P$, and a utility function $U(p) = \sum_{z : p(z) >0} p(z)u(z)$ where $p \in P$ and $u$ is a Bernoulli function. I don't see why if $u$ is a continuous bernoulli function, then U need to be continuous, in the sense that is satisfies the continuity axiom of Von-Neumann Morgenstern. I agree that if a preference relation is continuous then the utility function representing this preference is also continuous, but here I don't see the point.

Thank you

Comment: What is the formulation of "the continuity axiom of Von-Neumann Morgenstern?"

Comment: Continuity:
For all p, q, r ∈ P, if p$>~$  q$>~$ r then there exists a α ∈ [0, 1] such that
αp + (1 − α)r ∼ q.

Comment: @user38394 Have you tried proving this for the above case? Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: This holds whether $u$ is continuous or not.